# How to aproximate a function using another function - NN

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

So, there is the universal approximation theorem which says that a neural network can approximate any continuous function, provided it has at least one hidden layer and uses non-linear activation there.

So my doubt is as follows: "How do I approximate a function using neural networks with my input being other functions?"

Let's say I want to approximate *y = x + 1* and I have *z_1 = 2x, z_2  = 3x + 3* and *z_3 = 4x + 1*, with *x* being time variant. What I want my model to learn is the relationship between *z_1, z_2, z_3* and *y*, as I may write *y = -6 * z_1 - 1 * z_2 + 4 z_3* ( I want my network to learn this relationship).

From time *0 to T* I have the value of all functions and can do a supervised learning, but from *(T + 1) +*, I will only have *z_1, z_2* and *z_3* and so, I would be using the network to approximate the future values of *y* based on these *z functions (z_1, z_2, z_3)*.

How do I implement that on python using Keras? I used the following code but didn't get any decent results.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

n = 10000

def z_1(x):
    x_0 = []
    for i in x:
        x_0.append(2*i)
    return x_0

def z_2(x):
    x_0 = []
    for i in x:
        x_0.append(3*i + 3)
    return x_0

def z_3(x):
    x_0 = []
    for i in x:
        x_0.append(4* i + 1)
    return x_0

def z_0(x):
    x_0 = []
    for i in x:
        x_0.append(i + 1)
    return x_0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', input_dim=3))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

np.random.seed(seed = 2000)
input = np.random.random(n) * 10

dataset = z_0(input)
input_1 = z_1(input)
input_2 = z_2(input)
input_3 = z_3(input)

x_train = np.array([input_1[0:int(0.8*n)], input_2[0:int(0.8*n)], input_3[0:int(0.8*n)]])
y_train = np.array([dataset[0:int(0.8*n)]])
x_train = x_train.reshape(int(0.8*n), 3)
y_train = y_train.reshape(int(0.8*n),1)

es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                              min_delta=0,
                              patience=0,
                              verbose=0, mode='auto')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=128, callbacks = [es])


x_test = np.array([input_1[int(n-100):n], input_2[int(n-100):n], input_3[int(n-100):n]])
x_test = x_test.reshape(int(100), 3)

classes = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=128)

y_test = np.array([dataset[int(n-100):n]]).reshape(int(100),1)
plt.plot(y_test,c='b', label = 'test data')
plt.plot(classes,c='r', label = 'test result')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can't do this with a feedforward neural network. You need to do this with recurrent neural networks. Look up LSTM or GRU cells in Keras.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry for the late reply. Thanks. I switched to LSTM and it solved this problem pretty easily

Comment: Glad it did.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a feedforward neural network. You need to do this with recurrent neural networks. Look up LSTM or GRU cells in Keras.

https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/